# Location of local files in cordova

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, file-transfer

I'm using a video player which accepts an absolute path as parameter. If I put my video in the `www` folder, and use this code:

```
var path = cordova.file.applicationDirectory + 'www/myvideo.mp4';
GoogleVRPlayer.playVideo(path);
```

the video starts to play. The logs tell me the video is in:

```
file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/F4D23EDE-...-...-...-.../appname.app/www/myvideo.mp4
```

However, I don't want my video to be "baked in" the app: I want users to download it first. For the download, I use `cordova-plugin-file-transfer`:

```
download()
    {
        this.fileTransfer.download(
            this.uri,
            'cdvfile://localhost/persistent/path/to/downloads/',
            function(entry) {
                console.log("download complete: " + entry.toURL());
            },
            function(error) {
                console.log("download error source " + error.source);
                console.log("download error target " + error.target);
                console.log("download error code" + error.code);
            },
            false,
            {
                headers: {
                    "Authorization": "Basic dGVzdHVzZXJuYW1lOnRlc3RwYXNzd29yZA=="
                }
            }
        );
    }
```

This works fine too. The video downloads, and the log tells me the video is stored in

```
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/785BC9AF-...-...-...-.../Documents/path/to/downloads
```

Notice that the ID after "Application" is different for both files. Also, `appname.app` is not present in the URL of the downloaded file. But the video must be part of the app, because the app size increases after downloading the video...

How can I make the plugin download the file in the `www` folder, so I can play it? Or, which path should I use in the player so I can play the video downloaded in `path/to/downloads`?

**Update 1:** added extra info

**Update 2:**

I've changed the first path to

`cordova.file.documentsDirectory + 'path/to/downloads/myvideo.mp4';`.

Console tells me the video is stored in:
`file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A9B73639-...-...-...-.../Documents/path/to/downloads`

and the video it's trying to play is:
`file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A9B73639-...-...-...-.../Documents/path/to/downloads/myvideo.mp4`

However, the player doesn't play the file: `Failed to load video: The operation could not be completed`

Answer (score 1):

**Edit 2:**

The user fixed the issue.

It was a path error. Setting the name of the downloaded file as an argument in the fileTransfer function corrected the issue.

**Edit:**

I see you are using the VR player plugin. Looking at the documentation it uses Google's VR player as a basis for the plugin. Are you able to play the video in a web browser by filling the the guide here:

https://developers.google.com/vr/concepts/vrview-web

This will confirm that the video is compatible with the player that the plugin uses.

**Original Answer:**

If you want to store the file you download it is probably best to use the Cordova file plugin.

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file
```

Using this in conjunction with the file transfer plugin

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer
```

The problem is that, according to the file plugin documentation the /www folder is read only once the app is installed so you cannot download and store files there.

Documentation here.

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm using both plugins, and read the docs, but I can't get it to work. I'm not that skilled in working with cordova plugins unfortunately.

Comment: How are you trying to open the video?

Comment: Using `var path = cordova.file.documentsDirectory + 'path/to/downloads/myvideo.mp4'; GoogleVRPlayer.playVideo(path);`The video file should be in the right folder now (cf. update 2 in original question), but it still won't play.

Comment: I have added an edit to my answer because it maybe relevant to others with your problem.

Comment: The video is compatible with the player. When I put the web URL in the path, the video starts to play. The same goes for playing the video locally, when I put it directly in the `www` folder: no problems at all. Maybe the `Documents` folder needs read permissions or something?

Comment: The documents folder already has read permissions already. I suspect it's an issue with your path. Are you creating the path with the file plugin before you try an store the video there?

Comment: I managed to make it work by choosing a file name when storing the file. Maybe otherwise the file name after download is different from the original file name? Anyway, thanks for the help! Appreciate it.